# Python pattern matched Unions

Tags: python

I have a function which accepts a Callback.

```py
T = Type("T")
def invoke(tee: T, cb):
```

Now I want to ensure that only Callbacks are valid, which handle `T`. Additionally I want to allow for the Callback to optionally handle other types, too:

```
def iamanallowedcallback(first: Union[T, str]):

# def iwouldbeaforbiddencallback(first: Union[str, bytes]):
```

So it seems I would either need to have some kind of pattern matching or variadics to express this. I would imagine this to be something like:

```py
T = Type("T")
def invoke(tee: T, cb: Callback[Union[T, *]]): # star to match all Types in Union I do not care about
```

Is something similar already somehow possible in Python?

Comment: Added examples for possible callbacks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

`Union[T, S]` is a supertype of `T`, by the Python typing rules. If you're only calling `cb` on `T`, you can just do

```
def test(tee: T, fn: Callable[[T], None]) -> None:
    fn(tee)
```

And your function will happily accept arguments like

```
def foo(ignored: Union[int, str]) -> None:
    pass

test(1, foo)
```

Because `foo` has type `Callable[[Union[int, str]], None]`, and the argument position to `Callable` is [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), so `foo`'s type can be restricted to `Callable[[int], None]` (in the same way that we can safely treat a `str` as an `object`).